# printf type formating in Python is not returning expected result

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, printf, string-formatting

I want to embed the numerical variable inside the string with 2 decimal digits.

The code is the following:

```
x = 121.37890

print("The variable x has the value %.2d, which is surprising" % x)
```

It returns:

```
The variable x has the value 121, which is surprising
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See reference of [String format mini language](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#formatspec)
wich tells you what the specifier inside the formatting part are for. `d` for

> Decimal Integer. Outputs the number in base 10.

integer-like numbers without digits, `f` for

> Fixed point. Displays the number as a fixed-point number. The default precision is 6.

```
# python 2.x - discouraged to use it
print("The variable x has the value %.2f, which is surprising" % x) 

# explicit format syntax
print("The variable x has the value {:.2f}, which is surprising".format(x))

#implicit format syntax 
print(f'The variable x has the value {x:.2f}, which is surprising')
```

Output:

```
The variable x has the value 121.38, which is surprising
```

See [PEP-0498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#format-specifiers) for formatting in literal string interpolation (implicit fromat syntax).

A comparison of old vs. new syntax can be viewed in the docs https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#format-examples - it still works but you should switch using explicit / implicit formatting.

Further reading: [Python string formatting: % vs. .format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)

Answer (score 0):

Make it like

```
print("The variable x has the value %.2f, which is surprising" % x)
```

you have to use "fixed-point" instead of "decimal" in formatting.

returns:

```
The variable x has the value 121.38, which is surprising
```